# Why is this android device enlarging text?

Tags: android, css, zooming, text-size

The website is [tavistockrestaurants.com](http://tavistockrestaurants.com). We are trying to make this design work well in popular mobile devices. A particular android device seems to be enlarging the text, and I am unsure why. This causes the "contact" link in the top to wrap, and causes unecessary line breaks throughout our website. Notice the form is getting pushed below the images in this screenshot? It's supposed to have white space on the bottom!

We do have `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none` in place for all elements (using asterisk *). Is there an android equivelant? Has anyone experienced this on any android devices?

**This behavior does not occur on all android devices.** We have only seen this on Android 4.x, but I cannot reproduce it with my android 4.0 emulator.

What it currently looks like:
[image]

What it should look like:
[image]

(I do not have the specific device model used in the screen cap)

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but if you want to support mobile devices you would be better off using responsive templates such as http://getskeleton.com/ or http://www.initializr.com/. These will help your page look better on mobile devices rather than showing a page designed for a desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It wasn't originally designed to work on mobile devices, but the horizontal scrolling feels natural with touch interfaces so we would like to support it as is. I'm not sure if either of those would support horizontal scrolling like we have set up, but for future projects I'll probably try them out.

Comment: You could use a media query to give the top nav a little more fixed width on certain viewport pixel sizes... kind of a hacky workaround, but it's an idea.  :)

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, pixels are not pixels.

Or rather, 1 CSS pixel does not always map to 1 hardware pixel. On certain high-DPI Android devices, one CSS pixel can be 1.5 or 2 hardware pixels. The Opera guys [have a good overview on the topic.](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)

Answer (score 1):

Samuels answer is correct.

There is a workaround though. You can target specific devices and change the styles for that device specifically using classes or stylesheets. If you are using PHP you should be able to parse the "User-Agent" and determine which device the client is using and add a class to the body tag (and use that class to target that specific device in your CSS).

There are also services that will allow you to send users to a different version of the site depending on the device they are using. [Here](https://www.handsetdetection.com/) is a site that does the work for you.

There may also be device specific CSS being generated on loading the page. Using a CSS reset may also help your site be more cross-browser compatible.